# SV Sverchok : Points in mesh, go outside mesh

Tags: sverchok

I try to use the node [points_inside_mesh](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/nodes/analyzer/points_inside_mesh.rst) on a mesh that I create from a uv connection from two triangle.
So I got a 'Vector P filed' with many points and this mesh.

But when I apply the node there is some points who are outside
the mesh and not removed by the mask.

Is there a proper way to do that ?
I have try to apply "Recalc normals" to the mesh but it didn't solve this problème.

Until now it work well with box (and mesh create with boolean join boxes)
Is there an important rule for creating mesh from faces and/or surface to use "points inside mesh after" ?

Thanks for any advise who can put me on the path.
I have try many things and I don't know what can I do next...

Answer (score 2):

point_inside_mesh is agnostic to the input, as long as it is a manifold mesh.

for example: a torus/donut with distortion.

[image]

The only feature that the points_inside_mesh node won't handle automatically is multiplanar-ngons, if one of your meshes has a face where not all edges lie in the same plane, then you must pre-process that face to get useful results.

This for instance would not be a good input, the results of both "Regular" and "Multisample" modes are going to be undefined. The NGon will not be tessellated according to everyone's tastes.

[image]

This however, is fine. The ngon gets triangulated by the triangulate Mesh node. I'm not sure if it makes a difference to the triangulation bmesh.ops whether you triangulate the ngon while they're still flat, or if you insert that triangulate node after the Noise Displace.

[image]

the downside with the automated tessellation is that it behaves best with planar ngons, passing it non-planar / multi-planar ngons requires a more sophisticated algorithm to generate nice quad/tri topology.

Comment: Thank you it's all ready a big help.